# Has openDKIM been removed from repositories?

Tags: apt, postfix

Has openDKIM been removed from the package repositories? Using 18.04 lts and can't find or install. Is there a current recomended DKIM package?

Answer (score 0):

OpenDKIM *is* still in the Bionic 18.04 repositories. You need to enable the Universe pocket in your installation to get it.

Run the following:

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo apt update
sudo apt install opendkim opendkim-tools
```

This should then install OpenDKIM properly.

Comment: That did the trick... thanks heaps!